# JavaScript: Local Storage "boolean" not switching on first function call

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I'm working on a project that requires a tutorial overlay, I want to overlay to be toggle by a button, and I want to remember what state the button last in between page changes so the user doesn't have to "hide" to overlay every time they switch pages. Here is my code:

```
<!-- The two functions that do all the switching -->
<script>
        // This function changes the class of the overlay div and switches the Local Storage "boolean"
        function toggleOverlayVisibility(){
            document.getElementById('overlay').classList.toggle('hidden');
            sessionStorage.setItem('overlayVisibilityState', String(document.getElementById('overlay').classList.contains("hidden")));
        };
        // this function runs when the user switches pages and makes sure that the overlay is appropriately hidden or not.
        onload = function() {
            if(sessionStorage.getItem('overlayVisibilityState') == "true"){
               document.getElementById('overlay').classList.remove("hidden");
            } else if(sessionStorage.getItem('overlayVisibilityState') == "false") {
               document.getElementById('overlay').classList.add("hidden");
            } else {
               sessionStorage.setItem('overlayVisibilityState', "true");
               document.getElementById('overlay').classList.remove("hidden");
            }
 </script>

 <!-- the button -->
 <a href="#" onclick="toggleOverlayVisibility();"><img src="/static/icons/overlay.jpg" class="info-overlay"></a>

 <!-- the overlay div being toggled -->
 <div id="overlay" class="hidden">
        <!-- the overlay is split up into 4 sections so that the arrows always point at the right things regardless of windows size -->
        <p style="background-color:white; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%"></p>
        <img src="/static/overlays/main-upper-left.png" style="position:absolute; top:0;">
        <img src="/static/overlays/main-lower-left.png" style="position:absolute; bottom:50px; left:-30px;">
        <img src="/static/overlays/main-upper-right.png" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0;">
 </div>
```

Here is what happens, when the program first loads in there is no "overlayVisibilityState" in Local Storage, so the onload functions removes the hidden attribute so the overlay is displayed and sets Local Storage accordingly.

At this point if the user switches pages, the overlay displays on every page (as expected).

Now here is where it gets interesting, if the user presses the overlay button, the overlay is toggled - the "hidden" attribute is given to the div. However, Local Storage is not updated.

At this point if the user switches pages, the overlay displays on every page (when you would expect it not to display - you already turned it off after all).

This is where it gets fun, if you press the overlay button twice, the overlay does toggle twice (off and back on or vice versa) - but Local Storage only toggles once. Now the overlay Boolean is backwards! From this point on, toggling the overlay on and off more times switches the Local Storage once per button press.

I know that is a lot to follow, so I'll try to explain again using a pseudocode conditional.

```
if single toggle
     overlay switches = 1
     Local History switches = 0
if multiple toggles
     overlay switches = number of toggles
     Local History switches = number of toggles - 1
```

Alright here is my question, why is Local Storage not toggling on the first button press?
Let me know if I can clear anything up, or if you need more supporting code.

Comment: aside: `classList.toggle` returns a handy boolean, so you don't need to dom-drill twice. you should subscribe the _onload_ event better as well.

Comment: So do you want to have in a LocalHistory previous state, which is alway opposite of current?

Comment: A string that is "false" is actually *truthy* because it's not an empty string, `false` is a Boolean not a string which is the only type that Web Storage API deals with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 sessionStorage.setItem('overlayVisibilityState',
   String(document.getElementById('overlay').classList.contains("hidden")));
```

sets `overlayVisibilityState` in storage to "true" if the overlay is hidden.

But this logic

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('overlayVisibilityState') == "true"){
   document.getElementById('overlay').classList.remove("hidden");
} else if(sessionStorage.getItem('overlayVisibilityState') == "false") {
   document.getElementById('overlay').classList.add("hidden");
} else {
   sessionStorage.setItem('overlayVisibilityState', "true");
   document.getElementById('overlay').classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

treats "true" to mean the overlay is not hidden.

Try complementing the stored value when seting it:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('overlayVisibilityState',
 !document.getElementById('overlay').classList.contains("hidden"));
```

(`setItem` should convert the boolean value to a string automatically.)

Comment: Makes sense to use the actual state of the overlay as the Boolean to store, don't know why I didn't do that in the first place. I guess I'm still confused as to why it didn't work before, but this answer did fix the problem - so I'll give you the green check. Thank you!